# How to store and retrieve only single Row/Value from Realm in Android

Tags: android, realm

I'm working on Realm DB.

But I worked on saving multiple rows/values.

> I want to save only single row.

I've tried many approches but didn't get any result and the thing is I'm also not getting any error :(

How to deal with this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "single row"?

Comment: Means only one value

Comment: You should consider updating from 0.82.1 to 1.1.0, but make sure you keep track of the breaking changes that have happened since (`@Required` needed for non-nullable fields, `@PrimaryKey` became nullable so it needs `@Required` as well; `RealmResults` is no longer live-updating during transactions and `RealmResults` don't automatically sync until the next looper thread event)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining schema:

```
public class Dog extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    @Index
    private String name;

    public long getId() { return this.id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Writing into Realm:

```
Realm realm = null;
try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Dog dog = new Dog();
            dog.setId(1L);
            dog.setName("Fetch");
            realm.insertOrUpdate(dog);
        }
    });
} finally {
    if(realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Retrieving from database (sync):

```
Dog dog = realm.where(Dog.class).equalTo("id", 1L).findFirst();
if(dog != null) {
    // dog
}
```

Retrieving from database (async on UI thread, 0.84.0+):

```
private RealmResults<Dog> dogs;
private final RealmChangeListener<Dog> listener = new RealmChangeListener<Dog>() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<Dog> dogs) {
        if(dogs.isValid()) {
           if(dogs.isEmpty()) {
              // dog does not exist
           } else {
              Dog dog = dogs.get(0);
              // dog exists
           }
        }
    }
};

dogs = realm.where(Dog.class).equalTo("id", 1L).findAllAsync();
dog.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
```

Comment: @ProtonzzBaba in that case your Realm version is outdated, but you can also use `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(dog)`

Comment: uh... first I need to ask, do you use Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: Android studio and also by your above code I'm getting error of "Error during transaction"

Comment: You probably are saving a NULL value as a String and Realm 0.82.1 does not support NULL.

Comment: Anyways, you should probably update at least to 0.87.5 with `compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'`, but you should also consider updating to `1.1.1` as mentioned here https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation

Comment: ok after some huge modifications, i'm done. Thanks BTW marking as answer. @EpicPandaForce